# How to increase the length of select-options in UI

Tags: abap, sap-selection-screens

As I understood, select-options in abap just takes 45 characters from UI.

Whatever I assign the type of select-option, it doesnt take more then 45 characters.

```
SELECT-OPTIONS: s_key  FOR somlreci1-receiver NO INTERVALS VISIBLE LENGTH 100.
```

somlreci1-receiver is char(1215). But I cannot write more than 45 into that select-option.

Any way to increase this length ?

Comment: I just tried your code with another field and don't have this problem. What is the type of this field?

Comment: it is char(1215). are you sure you can write more than 45 characters into one input of select-options ?

Comment: The select-options field size limit is increased to 255 characters in Release 7.0, EhP3 and 7.3, EhP1 : http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_731/en/abennews-703-others.htm#!ABAP_MODIFICATION_1@1@

Comment: OK, well that explains it. Thanks @TimRadcliffe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This official link

http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_70/en/ABAPSELECT-OPTIONS.htm

says it isn't possible to pass input larger than 45 chars, sorry :|

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the documentation posted by @vlad-ardelean it mentions that:

> If a selection criterion for data types is supplied with data when
> calling up an executable program with SUBMIT
>
> ...
>
> If the selection criterion is declared with the addition NO-DISPLAY,
> no conversion routine or truncation will be performed for the first
> row either.

You could declare the select-options as NO-DISPLAY in your main program, then call it from a second program with

```
SUBMIT programname WITH so_field EQ lv_longdata SIGN 'I'.
```

...or similar to pass the long value to the main program. It's a pretty convoluted way of doing it, however.

Comment: well that's just SAP: disgusting solutions are the norm.

Comment: thanks @Tim Radcliffe. But I will not push on that. Vice versa, I will try to shorten the input.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @vlad-ardelean's answer: It might be interesting to note that in recent releases, the maximum field length was raised to 255 characters (see http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_731/en/ABAPSELECT-OPTIONS.htm).